# How to remove github repository stars older than two years?

Tags: github

Projects and their code base age, interests shift, things I liked two years ago are out of my focus. How can I automagically (e.g. bash script) revoke all stars older than two years? alternatively keep only the 200 recent stars? Is there service for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try GitHub API:

1. you can list repositories starred by you with star creation timestamps using https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/starring/#alternative-response-with-star-creation-timestamps-1
2. then write your script to select repos you want to unstar
3. unstar them through https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/starring/#unstar-a-repository.